# Calculator program in RISC-V assembly code

Tags: calculator, factorial, riscv

The first input/operand is s0, second input is the operation (s1), the third input is the second operand(s2).
For the 2nd input, s1:
if s1 ==0 : perform addition
1:subtraction
2:multiplication
3:division
4:power function
5:factorial function

Question 1) Solved.

I have no idea what's wrong with my code. If I wrote the division part first, followed by power function, it keeps dividing no matter I set the operation(s1) as 3 or 4. If I wrote the power function first, then the division, it keeps calculating A(s0) to the power of B(s2).

I have to sacrifice one to make another work by switching the order of the code. QQ

Question 2) Solved.
How should I implement the factorial function in here? I still do not get how (jal/jalr) recursive functions work in assembly code.

```
.globl __start

.rodata
    divide_by_zero: .string "divide by zero"

.text
__start:
    # Read first operand
    li a0, 5
    ecall
    mv s0, a0
    # Read operation
    li a0, 5
    ecall
    mv s1, a0
    # Read second operand
    li a0, 5
    ecall
    mv s2, a0

    li  t1,1  #load immediate
    li  t2,2
    li  t3,3
    li  t4,4
    li  t5,5
    li  t0,0  #counter for power
#Addition
    add s3,s0,s2  #s3=s0+s2
    beq s1,x0,exit  #if(s1==0)
#Subtraction
    sub s3,s0,s2  #s3=s0-s2
    beq s1,t1,exit  #if(s1==1)
#Multiplication
    mul s3,s0,s2  #s3=s0*s2
    beq s1,t2,exit  #if(s1==2)    
#Division
    beq s1,t3,division
#Factorial
    beq s1,t5,fact
#Power
    beq s1,t4,power
    power:
    add t6,s0,x0    #set t6 be s0 (base A)
    addi s3,x0,1    #set s3,return value to 1
    loop:
    bge t0,s2,exit  #if counter>= s2 (power B)
    mul s3, s3,s0   #multiply s3 by s0
    addi t0, t0, 1
    jal x0,loop
    
division:
    beq s2,x0,zero_except  #if s2==0, pass to zero_except
    div s3,s0,s2  #s3=s0/s2 (quotient)
    beq s1,t3,exit  #if(s1==3)

fact:
    addi s3,x0,1    #set s3,return value to 1
    rep:
    blt s0,t1,exit
    mul s3,s3,s0
    addi s0,s0,-1
    jal x0,rep

exit:
    # Output the result
    li a0, 1
    mv a1, s3
    ecall
    # Exit program(necessary)
    li a0, 10
    ecall

zero_except:
    # Divide by zero exception
    li a0, 4
    la a1, divide_by_zero
    ecall
    # Exit the program(necessary)
    li a0, 10
    ecall
```

Comment: What happens when you single step in the debugger?

Comment: I found out the value for s3 has went through addition, subtraction, etc as well after single step in the debugger. The order above works for power function, but except if the power(s2) is zero, it shows "divide by zero" because the divide by zero condition is written before

Comment: So far I built a division function so if s1 == 3, then pass to it. Now only factorial function is left to do.

Comment: Oh i got the factorial done